# How do I PowerPoint 2010 Alignment Issue?

Tags: powerpoint

We are currently using Office 2010 on all of our computers. All users create PowerPoint documents and share them with one another. With one of the four computers was sent a document that is not showing correctly at any of the four PC's.. .. On the every PC that is having the problem the text will not align with the text box, it will fall out of the bottom or overlap words. I have attempted changing printer drivers, checking if they're using different fonts and repairing the office installation. I'm not sure what else I can check that would resolve this issue. Any input would be greatly appreciated. All other documents such as Word and Excel function properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling this is happening after a copy/paste and not just when they open the file and view it in slide show view. Can't it be a font issue like, the problem computer having a font that seems to be the same but in fact is not?
That deformating issue in a PPT, already happened to me with an OTF being automatically replaced by a TTF with the same name, in a second computer... Or it could be because the file is corrupted. Look at this reputable source also.
http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/questions/powerpoint-file-crashes-powerpoint-upon-opening/

Comment: Thanks for the help! fortunately the problem was resolved.